# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo. Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.vision.view.VisionView

Tags: java, android, mapbox-android

I'm new to android development and am having trouble with trying to run and implement some of the sample code from mapbox android example. link to the [git repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-vision-android/tree/dev/Examples/src/main) The app crashes as soon as it's launched. This was the error that I keep getting.

[image: error message]

**activity_external_video_source.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.mapbox.vision.view.VisionView
    android:id="@+id/vision_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:visualization_mode="clear" />
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/speed_alert_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/speed_limit_view_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/speed_limit_view_height"
    android:layout_gravity="end|top"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView-->
        android:id="@+id/speed_sign_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/speed_limit_view_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/speed_limit_view_height"
       android:src="@drawable/speed_limit_normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speed_value_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/speed_limit_speed_view_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/speed_limit_speed_view_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="SpUsage"
        tools:text="40" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**ExternalVideoSourceActivity**

```
  package com.example.myapplication;

  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.os.HandlerThread;

  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

  import com.mapbox.vision.VisionManager;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.interfaces.VisionEventsListener;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.AuthorizationStatus;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.Camera;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.Country;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.FrameSegmentation;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.classification.FrameSignClassifications;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.detection.FrameDetections;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.frame.ImageFormat;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.frame.ImageSize;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.position.VehicleState;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.road.RoadDescription;
  import com.mapbox.vision.mobile.core.models.world.WorldDescription;
  import com.mapbox.vision.video.videosource.VideoSource;
  import com.mapbox.vision.video.videosource.VideoSourceListener;
  import com.mapbox.vision.view.VisionView;

  import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

  import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;



  public class ExternalVideoSourceActivity extends BaseActivity {
// Video file that will be processed.
private static final String PATH_TO_VIDEO_FILE = "path_to_video_file";

private VideoSourceListener videoSourceListener;
private VisionView visionView;
private HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("VideoDecode");
private boolean visionManagerWasInit = false;

// VideoSource that will play the file.
private VideoSource customVideoSource = new VideoSource() {
    @Override
    public void attach(@NotNull VideoSourceListener videoSourceListener) {
        // video source is attached, we can start decoding frames from video and feeding them to Vision SDK.
        ExternalVideoSourceActivity.this.videoSourceListener = videoSourceListener;
        handlerThread.start();
        new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()).post(() -> startFileVideoSource());
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
        videoSourceListener = null;
        handlerThread.quitSafely();
    }
};

// VisionEventsListener handles events from Vision SDK on background thread.
private VisionEventsListener visionEventsListener = new VisionEventsListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAuthorizationStatusUpdated(@NotNull AuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFrameSegmentationUpdated(@NotNull FrameSegmentation frameSegmentation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFrameDetectionsUpdated(@NotNull FrameDetections frameDetections) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFrameSignClassificationsUpdated(@NotNull FrameSignClassifications frameSignClassifications) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoadDescriptionUpdated(@NotNull RoadDescription roadDescription) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onWorldDescriptionUpdated(@NotNull WorldDescription worldDescription) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVehicleStateUpdated(@NotNull VehicleState vehicleState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraUpdated(@NotNull Camera camera) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCountryUpdated(@NotNull Country country) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateCompleted() {
    }
};

@Override
protected void initViews() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_external_video_source);
    visionView = findViewById(R.id.vision_view);
}

@Override
protected void onPermissionsGranted() {
    startVisionManager();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    startVisionManager();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopVisionManager();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    visionView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    visionView.onPause();
}

private void startVisionManager() {
    if (/*allPermissionsGranted() && */!visionManagerWasInit) {
        VisionManager.create(customVideoSource);
        visionView.setVisionManager(VisionManager.INSTANCE);
        VisionManager.setVisionEventsListener(visionEventsListener);
        VisionManager.start();

        visionManagerWasInit = true;
    }
}

private void stopVisionManager() {
    if (visionManagerWasInit) {
        VisionManager.stop();
        VisionManager.destroy();

        visionManagerWasInit = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Decodes video source frame by frame and feeds frames to Vision SDK.
 */
private void startFileVideoSource() {
    // Use MediaMetadataRetriever to decode video.
    // It isn't the fastest approach to decode videos and you probably want some other method.
    // if FPS is important (eg. MediaCodec).
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(PATH_TO_VIDEO_FILE);

    // Get video frame size.
    int frameWidth = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
    int frameHeight = Integer.parseInt(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));
    ImageSize imageSize = new ImageSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    // ByteBuffer to hold RGBA bytes.
    ByteBuffer rgbaByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(frameWidth * frameHeight * 4);

    // Get duration.
    long duration = Long.parseLong(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));

    try {
        // Get frames one by one with 1 second intervals.
        for (int seconds = 0; seconds < duration; seconds++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = retriever
                    .getFrameAtTime(
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(seconds),
                            MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST
                    )
                    .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);

            bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(rgbaByteBuffer);

            videoSourceListener.onNewFrame(
                    new VideoSourceListener.FrameHolder.ByteBufferHolder(rgbaByteBuffer),
                    ImageFormat.RGBA,
                    imageSize
            );
            rgbaByteBuffer.clear();
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Error Code**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 28188
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.vision.view.VisionView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.vision.view.VisionView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.vision.view.VisionView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
        at com.mapbox.vision.view.VisionView.(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-dqVfdYY3dsKSWn0I2iNVNw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-dqVfdYY3dsKSWn0I2iNVNw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myapplication-dqVfdYY3dsKSWn0I2iNVNw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)

Comment: have you checked this answer?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263653/android-mapbox-inflating-error-didnt-find-class-mapview

Comment: if you post complete error (i mean the cause of it which is probably a few lines blew ) it would help a lot

Comment: updated to include the error code